# Can nginx location blocks match a URL query string?

Tags: nginx, http

Can [nginx](https://www.nginx.com/) [`location` blocks](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/nginx-web-server/#locations) match a URL query string?

For example, what location block might match HTTP `GET` request

```
GET /git/sample-repository/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack HTTP/1.1
```

Comment: I'd guess "location /git/sample-repository/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack" as nginx just does string comparison.

Comment: String comparison of the entire URL or just the part before the question mark (`?`)?

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15713934/how-to-match-question-mark-as-regexp-on-nginx-conf-location, nginx considers the URI to be only the part before the question mark.  Is this still the case?

Comment: You were right, I was wrong. In A location block "the matching is performed against a normalized URI". You could try it with a rewrite which uses the $request_uri  ("full original request URI (with arguments)")

Comment: Where did you find this quotation?

Comment: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_request_uri

Comment: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location

Comment: It's not clear from http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite that `rewrite` regular expression matches `$request_uri`.

Comment: "If the specified regular expression matches a request URI, URI is changed as specified in the replacement string."
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47606/discussion-between-derek-mahar-and-josefscript).

Comment: Some last clarification as I stumbled over this problem myself: https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html clearly states: _"Note that locations of all types test only a URI part of request line without arguments. This is done because arguments in the query string may be given in several ways"_

Answer (score 63, accepted):

> Can nginx location blocks match a URL query string?

**Short answer**: No.

**Long answer**: There is a workaround if we have only a handful of such location blocks.

Here's a sample workaround for 3 location blocks that need to match specific query strings:

```
server {
  #... common definitions such as server, root
    
  location / {
    error_page 418 = @queryone;
    error_page 419 = @querytwo;
    error_page 420 = @querythree;

    if ( $query_string = "service=git-receive-pack" ) { return 418; }
    if ( $args ~ "service=git-upload-pack" ) { return 419; }
    if ( $arg_somerandomfield = "somerandomvaluetomatch" ) { return 420; }

    # do the remaining stuff
    # ex: try_files $uri =404;
    
  }

  location @queryone {
    # do stuff when queryone matches
  }

  location @querytwo {
    # do stuff when querytwo matches
  }

  location @querythree {
    # do stuff when querythree matches
  }
}
```

You may use $query_string, $args or $arg_fieldname. All will do the job. You may know more about [error_page in the official docs](http://nginx.org/r/error_page).

Warning: Please be sure **not** to use the [standard HTTP codes](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html#name-status-codes).

Comment: Interesting approach!  May I recommend `$args ~ "service=git-send-pack"` instead of `$args = "service=git-send-pack"`?  This form accommodates multiple query parameters.

Comment: `git-send-pack` should also read `git-upload-pack`.

Comment: Yes. +1 for tilde to match multiple queries!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40313590/107158 illustrates the approach that I followed to handle query string arguments.  Like your answer, mine uses `if` and `$arg_fieldname`, but uses `rewrite` instead of `error_page` and `location @name`.  Note that in that example, my attempts at using `@name` for the *replacement* parameter in `rewrite` were unsuccessful.

Comment: By the way, it should be `$args ~` and `$arg_somerandomfield =`.

Comment: Yes. Good catch! Yes, both "return" and "rewrite ... last" work correctly inside an "if" statement as per the docs... https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/ .

Comment: One can also use nginx `map` feature for this purpose, which is faster.

Comment: http://www.redant.com.au/ruby-on-rails-devops/manage-ssl-redirection-in-nginx-using-maps-and-save-the-universe/ explains why and how to use `map`.

Comment: Why the standard HTTP code must not be used?

Comment: When we use standard HTTP code, Nginx will show the standard error page, rather than (internally) redirecting to the named location block.

Comment: +1 for 418 I'm a teapot – also this is a great solution

Comment: The `error_page` directive can be misleading. If a query parameter is set, that should not be considered as an error. I wonder if there is another `nginx` directive to be used instead of `error_page`.

Comment: Good point @W.M. . The `error_page` usage to safely change the location was directly inspired by https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/#what-to-do-instead . Probably, there will be an alternative way to do this in the future, that doesn't mislead.

Comment: @PothiKalimuthu, thanks for clarifying this. What I have done in the meanwhile is to replace the `query` parameter by a url path one like this `feedback/{auth_key}` instead of `/feedback?auth_key=abc`. This way I don't need to use `if`, I can define location pattern using `regex` and that's it.

Comment: note: `$query_string` or `$args` won't match a url like `/example/service=git-receive-pack`, even though once rewritten it has that query, in this case `$request_uri` seems to be the only option

Comment: @PothiKalimuthu you look very experienced on Nginx, can u help me problem here https://serverfault.com/questions/1035805/how-to-serve-php-on-nginx-on-a-query-parameter-amp-1

Answer (score 11):

I know this question is over a year old, but I've spent the last few days destroying my brain over a similar problem. I wanted different authentication and handling rules for public and private repos, including pushing and pulling. This is what I finally came up with, so I figured I'd share. I know `if` is a tricky directive, but this seems to work for me just fine:

```
# pattern for all repos, public or private, followed by username and reponame
location ~ ^(?:\/(private))?\/([A-Za-z0-9]+)\/([A-Za-z0-9]+)\.git(\/.*)?$ {

    # if this is a pull request
    if ( $arg_service = "git-upload-pack" ) {

        # rewrite url with a prefix
        rewrite ^ /upload$uri;

    }

    # if this is a push request
    if ( $arg_service = "git-receive-pack" ) {

        # rewrite url with a prefix
        rewrite ^ /receive$uri;

    }

}

# for pulling public repos
location ~ ^\/upload(\/([A-Za-z0-9]+)\/([A-Za-z0-9]+)\.git(\/.*)?)$ {

    # auth_basic "git";
    # ^ if you want

    # ...
    # fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/fcgiwrap.socket;
    # ...

}

# for pushing public repos
location ~ ^\/receive(\/([A-Za-z0-9]+)\/([A-Za-z0-9]+)\.git(\/.*)?)$ {

    # auth_basic "git";
    # ^ if you want

    # ...
    # fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/fcgiwrap.socket;
    # ...

}

# for pulling private repos
location ~ ^\/upload\/private(\/([A-Za-z0-9]+)\/([A-Za-z0-9]+)\.git(\/.*)?)$ {

    # auth_basic "git";
    # ^ if you want

    # ...
    # fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/fcgiwrap.socket;
    # ...

}

# for pushing private repos
location ~ ^\/receive\/private(\/([A-Za-z0-9]+)\/([A-Za-z0-9]+)\.git(\/.*)?)$ {

    # auth_basic "git";
    # ^ if you want

    # ...
    # fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/fcgiwrap.socket;
    # ...

}
```

Comment: As NGINX uses PCRE library, I would suggest to use `\w` instead of `[A-Za-z0-9_]` to diminish verbosity.

Comment: In my example, I've explicitly excluded underscores, so `\w` wouldn't work in my case. I upvoted the comment anyway, and I agree that this would be better in general.

Answer (score -1):

There is another way this can be done, if you are using nginx as a proxy.

set a variable in the server block:

```
set $nocache="0";
```

Inside the location block, add the if:

```
if ( $arg_<query string to match> = "<query string value>") { set $nocache "1"; }
```

And add two new proxy directives:

```
proxy_cache_bypass $nocache ;
proxy_no_cache $nocache ;
```

it will always forward to the upstream server with no cache